# How to remove a previously toggled class when we toggle another class by click event

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I dont use Jquery and dont want to , I wanted to toggle a class again once next item is toggled with same class. so the class from previous one is removed. and only one class is toggled on at a time.

I tried adding `document.getElementsByClassName(".panel").removeClass("open");`
to the function to first remove all toggled class('open')
but that doesnt work.
i tried adding an id and trying to remove a class from that id still doesn't work

```
function toggleOpen() {

     document.getElementsByClassName(".panel").removeClass("open");//this give me error
      this.classList.toggle('open');


    }
    function toggleActive(e) {
      if (e.propertyName.includes('flex')) {
        this.classList.toggle('open-active');
      }

    }



    const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
    panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
    panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('transitionend', toggleActive));
```

Result

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).removeClass is not a function
```

Comment: Related: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `classList.remove("open")`, not `removeClass("open")`

Also, it wouldn't work because `getElementsByClassName` would return a collection of elements, and you can't remove the class from them all at once.
You'd have to call it for each element in the panel.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(".panel")).forEach(element => element.classList.remove("open"))
```

Or without turning it to an array first you can do

```
const panels = document.getElementsByClassName(".panel")
for (let panel of panels) {
  panel.classList.remove("open")
}
```

Comment: ```document.getElementsByClassName(".panel").forEach(element => element.classList.remove("open"))```                   i get this error                                              ```Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.toggleOpen (index-START.html:157)```

Comment: Oh yes, you must turn it to an array to use `forEach` but you can do it normally with a for loop, so  you must turn it to an array first `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(".panel")).forEach(element => element.classList.remove("open"))`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding event listener to each element, `document.getElementsByClassName(".panel").removeClass("open");` is not required. `this` inside the function will refer to clicked element.

`removeClass` is jquery method, which will not be available.
`document.getElementsByClassName` returns list of elements, so you need to loop over it.

Try following example.

```js
function toggleColor() {
      this.classList.toggle('red');
}


const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleColor));
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="panel green">H1<p>
<p class="panel red">H2<p>
<p class="panel green">H3<p>
<p class="panel  red">H4<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to remove previous class from link

```
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('ul li a');

function removeActiveClass() {
  navLinks.forEach((val)=>{
    val.parentNode.classList.remove('active-nav');
  })
}

navLinks.forEach((val)=>{
  val.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    removeActiveClass();
    val.parentNode.classList.add('active-nav');
  })
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).